# Script error: can't get file in Applescript?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to create a plist file with applescript, which will contain predetermined text. I need to be able to write this text to the file "`plistfile.plist`", but I get the error "`Can't get file (alias "MacintoshHD:Users:myusername:Desktop:plistfile.plist")`" whenever I run my script. My script is:

```
set plistfilename to POSIX file "/Users/myusername/Desktop/plistfile.plist" as alias

set ptext to "plist text"

set plist to open for access file plistfilename & "plistfile.plist" with write permission
write ptext to plist
close access file plist
```

I'm not very familiar with any of this, but I thought this made sense. I've done some Googling and I haven't found this issue anywhere else. If anyone can let me know what I'm missing I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The code fails because a coercion `as alias` throws an error if the file does not exist.

This is the usual and reliable way to write text to a file

```
set plistfilename to (path to desktop as text) & "plistfile.plist"

set ptext to "plist text"

try
    set fileDescriptor to open for access file plistfilename with write permission
    write ptext to fileDescriptor as «class utf8»
    close access fileDescriptor
on error
    try
        close access file plistfilename
    end try
end try
```

**Edit:**

Consider that the result of the script is a simple `.txt` file even if you pass the `.plist` extension.

To create a **real** property list file you could use `System Events`:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set rootDictionary to make new property list item with properties {kind:record}
    -- create new property list file using the empty dictionary list item as contents
    set the plistfilename to "~/Desktop/plistfile.plist"
    set plistFile to ¬
        make new property list file with properties {contents:rootDictionary, name:plistfilename}
    make new property list item at end of property list items of contents of plistFile ¬
        with properties {kind:boolean, name:"booleanKey", value:true}
    make new property list item at end of property list items of contents of plistFile ¬
        with properties {kind:string, name:"stringKey", value:"plist text"}
end tell
```

The script creates this property list file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>booleanKey</key>
    <true/>
    <key>stringKey</key>
    <string>plist text</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```